# how can i import photos from a canon digital camera?

Tags: 12.04, canon

i installed ubuntu 12.04 on my friend's uncle's laptop.His uncle uses canon digital camera.Is there a possible way to imort photos using ubuntu

Comment: You just need to attach the camera to the laptop using the USB cable that comes with it. It will then open as a mounted device.

Answer (score 5):

Usually one can simply connect a USB device to Ubuntu and the device will automatically recognise it as a camera, or if this doesn't happen you could try inserting the SD card directly into the computer.
Then one can open `Shotwell` and follow the instructions [here](http://yorba.org/shotwell/help/import-camera.html)

1. Connect the camera to your computer and switch it on. Shotwell will
   detect it and list it in the sidebar.
2. Select the camera in the sidebar. Previews of each photo on the camera will be displayed.
3. If you like, you can choose a set of specific photos to import. To do this, hold down the Ctrl key and click to select individual
   photos. You can hold down Shift and click to select a range of
   photos too.
4. Click either Import Selected or Import All. The photos will be copied from the camera and saved on your computer.

Comment: Also works on 16.04